# Port forwarding for SSH and VNC for a PC behind a Linux gateway Sharing Internet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, port-forwarding, vnc

I'm sharing my WiFi Internet connection through my Linux (Arch or Ubuntu) PC using the Gui interface to the ethernet port to a switch. wlp2s0 and enp5s0 are the two interfaces, wifi and ethernet.

Gateway:
The shared pc gets 192.168.1.20 from a router on interface wlp2s0.

The shared PC also uses the gateway IP of 10.42.0.1 on interface enp5s0.

PC behind gateway:
The PC I want to access gets 10.42.0.251 via ethernet. 
Internet works fine, local VNC/SSH access to and from this to the gateway also works.

I want to be able to SSH and VNC into from outside the network on ports 2022 and 5901 but cannot get port forwarding to work. The ports are open on the Netgear router hooked up to the cable modem.  In Windows ICS, I can easily open ports in the "Share" tab and can do what I want to.  In Linux, however, I've tried many iptables commands but no success.

Can someone please give me the specific commands to do this? I hate that Windows can do this so easily but Linux cannot :p